# Using Algolia with React Native Hooks with connectors

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, algolia, search-box

I'm using Algolia in my mobile Application with Expo and I don't know why but when I use my SearchBox it do nothing, this is my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If someone has any idea for what my searchBox never search ? // I don't have any warning for that actualy